# Как тестировать часть кода через Mocha.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, тестирование, mocha

Вникаю в js и тестирование, возник вопрос.
Есть скрипт с разными функциями - script.js;
установлен nodejs с chai.js и mocha.js;
написал пример теста, он спотыкается, говоря что "viewCookie is not defined"

```
    var assert = require('assert');
describe('Cookies', function() {
    describe('viewCookie()', function() {
        it('should return undefined', function() {
            assert.equal(undefined, viewCookie());
        });
    });
});
```

как правильно запустить тест только одной функции из script.js?
и как правильно к нему обратиться из дирректории, где лежит тест?
а также что делать если в функции запрашиваются параметры вроде document. итд, хотелось бы как то подставлять туда возможные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключить файл script.js как модуль. То есть через `require('./script.js')` (путь указан относительно файла с тестом). Но в этом случае вы должны в файле script.js добавить в конце конструкцию `module.exports = *значение*`. Вместо *значения* будет объект содержащий функции которые вы собираетесь протестировать, например, {viewCookie: viewCookie, anotherFunction: anotherFunction}
Тогда в модуле теста подключив файл с функциями, вы можете вызывать их через переменную.

```
var script =  require('./script.js');
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Cookies', function() {
    describe('viewCookie()', function() {
        it('should return undefined', function() {
            assert.equal(undefined, script.viewCookie());
        });
    });
});
```

Если вы хотите этот файл с функциями использовать в браузере, то стоит сделать проверку на наличие module.exports, так как эта конструкция свойственна для Node.js
Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = *значение*;
}
```